# Menu want get fixed to the top on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to accomplish a simple effect of sticking the menu to top of the browser window when scrolling passes a certain point, but something went wrong and the menu wont get fixed to the top. From the libraries I'm using jQuery and animate it.

My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<nav class="animatedParent">
    <ul class="animated bounceInUp delay-750">
        <li class="animated"><a href="#">O meni</a></li>
        <li class="animated"><a href="#">Katalog</a></li>
        <li class="animated"><a href="#">Razno</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.fixedNav {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .8);
    height: 100px;
}

nav {
    width: 400px;
    margin:  20px auto;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 130px;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 500ms linear all;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #123456;
    transition: 500ms linear all;
}
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav ul li").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass("wiggle");
    });
    $("nav ul li").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("wiggle");
    });

    var nav = $("nav").offsetTop();
    if($(window).scrollTop() > nav) {
        $("nav").addClass("fixedNav");
        console.log('Hello!');
    } else {
        $("nav").removeClass("fixedNav");
    }
});
```

Comment: You check position just once but you need to check it on each scroll event. So add scroll event listener and then you achieve result what you want

Comment: $("body").scroll(function{
    var nav = $("nav").offsetTop();
    if($(window).scrollTop() > nav) {
      $("nav").addClass("fixedNav");
      console.log('Hello!');
    } else {
      $("nav").removeClass("fixedNav");
    }
  });    and it still wont work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off, you only use the code once, which is when the document is loaded. You're going to want to check everytime you scroll the document as the code should obivously be triggered once you scroll a certain amount.

```js
$(document).scroll(function(){
  var nav = $("nav").height();
  if($(window).scrollTop() > nav) {
    $("nav").addClass("fixedNav");
  } else {
    $("nav").removeClass("fixedNav");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
background: black; 
height:700px;
}
.fixedNav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .8);
  height: 100px;
}
nav {
  display: block;
height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin:  20px auto;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 130px;
}
nav ul li a {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 500ms linear all;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #123456;
  transition: 500ms linear all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="animatedParent nav">
      <ul class="animated bounceInUp delay-750">
        <li class="animated"><a href="#">O meni</a></li>
        <li class="animated"><a href="#">Katalog</a></li>
        <li class="animated"><a href="#">Razno</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the event `scroll` and check the offset there.

When the user is scrolling, `toggleClass` will add/remove the class based on the condition `$window.scrollTop() > navOffset` which will return `true` or `false`

```
var $window = $(window);
var $nav = $('nav');
var navOffset = $nav.offsetTop();

$window.on('scroll', function() {
  $nav.toggleClass('fixedNav', $window.scrollTop() > navOffset);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add an scroll event to check your scroll position

for example:

```
$(document).scroll(()=>{...});
```

like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/benjamingoek/rwz0fjq6/)

This is a very plain demo, it only demonstrate wha i meant

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [scrollMonitor](https://github.com/stutrek/scrollMonitor) to accomplish your task as scroll monitoring have its own caveats.

You can let `scrollMonitor` to lock position of your menu when it leaves viewport, something like this:

```
var $menu = document.querySelector('nav'); // It is better to use CSS class name instead
var watcher = scrollMonitor.create($menu);
watcher.lock();
watcher.exitViewport(function() {
    $menu.classList.add('fixedNav');
});
watcher.enterViewport(function() {
    $menu.classList.remove('fixedNav');
});
```

Please refer [this example](https://stutrek.github.io/scrollMonitor/demos/fixed.html) as it closely matches your task.

Comment: C'mon, there's no reason to use the next library (when jQuery is already used) just to achieve such a simple thing! I can't quite understand the trend for Library Driven Development...

Comment: @MichałKostrzyński C'mon, there is not reason to use the next library (jQuery, 90kb minified) just to achieve such a simple thing when it is possible to use 8kb of dedicated library! I can't quite understand the trend for re-inventinig whe wheel. :)

Comment: Flying, my point is that he's already using jQuery. If he were to resign of it that would make sense, though there are still way easier methods like: `var scrollTop = (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;` which takes like 100 bytes.

Comment: @MichałKostrzyński I hope you understand that it was a joke. Seriously speaking there is other issues author will deal with like events debouncing and so on. jQuery is general purpose library that provides basic abstraction, but such nuances are out of its scope and hence author will need to find them out by himself, so it will take him some time to implement not just working, but correctly working solution. Because of this fact it may be better idea to use well established solution from the start. Moreover it is pretty cheap to use as it have no dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You don't fire the check for the current scroll on `scroll` event. That's an event you're looking for.
Also you could check the scrollTop on the document (it's more error proof in jQuery), not on the window as it doesn't always work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("nav ul li").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass("wiggle");
  });
  $("nav ul li").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("wiggle");
  });
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
      var nav = $("nav").offsetTop();
      if($(document).scrollTop() > nav) {
        $("nav").addClass("fixedNav");
        console.log('Hello!');
      } else {
        $("nav").removeClass("fixedNav");
      }
  })
});
```

Answer (score -2):

That is what you are looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("nav ul li").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass("wiggle");
  }) ;
  $("nav ul li").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("wiggle");
  }) ;
});

$(document).ready(fixedHeader) ;

$(window).scroll(fixedHeader) ;

function fixedHeader() {
  var nav = parseInt($("nav").css("margin-top")) ;

  if($(window).scrollTop() > nav) {
    $("nav").addClass("fixedNav");
  }
  else {
    $("nav").removeClass("fixedNav");
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 1000px;
}
.fixedNav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .8);
  height: 100px;
}
nav {
  width: 400px;
  margin:  20px auto;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 130px;
}
nav ul li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 500ms linear all;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #123456;
  transition: 500ms linear all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="animatedParent">
  <ul class="animated bounceInUp delay-750">
    <li class="animated"><a href="#">O meni</a></li>
    <li class="animated"><a href="#">Katalog</a></li>
    <li class="animated"><a href="#">Razno</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: First of all, that code formatting is ugly (space before semicolon, really?). 
Secondly, if you've extracted the scroll event handler to the separate function there's no reason to create a new anonymous function on each scroll event fired as it would impact performance significantly in more complex cases. You could just pass it like this instead: `$(window).scroll(fixedHeader);`